# google spreadsheet -access empty cells using nodejs

Tags: node.js

when i was trying to use optional data like min_row,max_row,return_empty under getCells function in npm googlespreadsheet using nodejs.I am not successful doing so.can anyone say me the syntax for using options under getCells function

This is the snippet i tried

```
   my_sheet.getCells(1,{minRows: 2,maxRows:3,returnEmpty:true},function(err,data) {
   console.log(data.length);
   // console.log(data);
   });
```

and also i need to read the empty cells inbetween group of cells while accessing  googlespreadsheet using nodejs.Is there any way for it???I want a way for it using nodejs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Docs](https://github.com/theoephraim/node-google-spreadsheet#googlespreadsheetgetcellsworksheet_id-options-callback)

> **GoogleSpreadsheet.getCells(worksheet_id, options, callback)**
>
> Get an array of cell objects.
>
> - worksheet_id - the index of the sheet to add to (index starts at 1)
> - options (optional)
>
>   - min-row - row range min (uses #s visible on the left)
>   - max-row - row range max min-col - column range min (uses numbers, not letters!)
>   - max-col - column range max
>   - return-empty - include empty cells (boolean)

```
my_sheet.getCells(1, {
    'min-row': 2,
    'min-row': 3,
    'return-empty': true
}, function(err, data) {
    console.log(data.length);
});
```